# Single.fromCallable not correctly implemented

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I am using a Single.fromCallable as follows:

```
lateinit var appAPI: AppAPI

    fun getUsersLinkedInSettings() {
        Single.fromCallable {
            appApi.getSettings()
        }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                { result -> onRetrieveUserSettingsSuccess(result) },
                { onRetrievePostListError() }
            )
    }

private fun onRetrieveUserSettingsSuccess(userSettings: UserSettings) {

}
```

The appApi is defined as follows:

```
interface AppAPI {
    @GET("/settings")
    fun getSettings(): Single<UserSettings>
}
```

I get a compile error where it expects result to be UserSettings but found Single. How do I convert Single to just UserSettings

Comment: `Single.defer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSettings` returns `Single<UserSettings>`. In your code, you wrap it with `Single.fromCallable` so the result is `Single<Single<UserSettings>>`.

Try to call `getSettings` directly.

```
appApi
    .getSettings()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { result -> onRetrieveUserSettingsSuccess(result) },
        { onRetrievePostListError() }
    )
```

Comment: Don't I still need the fromCallable since the api call will take a while to run?

Comment: You can think of a Single (which is something like an Observable) as an asynchronous stream which always either emits one value or an error notification. Because it's asynchronous, you don't need to use `fromCallable`.

Comment: You use `fromCallable` when you have a piece of code that needed to be wrapped into a `Single` and this code needs to be executed on subscribe time for each individual subscriber.