# Is the AsyncTask most productive technique for slow background tasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-task

There are few techniques to execute slow code that returns some data in Android. By slow code I mean network, file, database access etc.

1. `Thread` and `Runnable` can be used, but I found that getting produced data from a `Runnable` is hard/not productive.
2. We can use `Service` with `Broadcast`, but I found that this is also not productive technique.
3. We have nice `AsyncTask` class in Android.

   Is this last approach most productive way to execute slow background operations that return some data, or there is something better in Android?

Comment: `AsyncTask` has been deprecated for a few years. "`Service` with `Broadcast`" is unrelated to threads. Reactive frameworks (RxJava, Kotlin coroutines) are the recommended approaches nowadays for general-purpose stuff. But the answer may vary depending on scenario: threading models for games will be very different than threading models for social media clients, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. I'm trying with RxJava/RxAndroid, but I can't find learning resources suitable to my needs. Most RxJava tutorials elaborate about many operators, mappings, filters, timers, intervals and after few hours I can't find example that shows how to call a function with a parameter and get returned value on another thread...

Comment: `Single.fromCallable({}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe({}) {}`. The `fromCallable()` lambda would wrap your function call. The first `subscribe()` lambda gets your result. The second `subscribe()` lambda gets called if an exception is raised, such as from that function call. Change the two schedulers as needed based on what threads/pools you want to use. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56209888/115145.

Comment: Well, to make it more readable for learning I have created `Callable<String>` and put it as .fromCallable() parameter and `new SingleObserver<String>()` as parameter of .subscribe(). Now I can get my `String` result (awesome!), but now I cannot pass parameter to my background code (not awesome).

Comment: You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] that shows what you are trying to do and asking for help in converting it to RxJava 2 or RxJava 3 (whichever you are trying to use).

Comment: @CommonsWare I did. It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73789460/how-to-use-rxjava-rxandroid-in-android-to-make-slow-network-call-and-update-th Thanks for your help.